# scroll lock in popup-overlay is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using popup-overlay js plugin. The scrolllock option seems to be not working. Anyone know how should I fix this?

All I need is to be able to disable the page scrolling when the pop-up is active. and enable page scrolling when it's closed for mousewheel and touch divices.

```
$('#theDIV').popup({
  scrolllock: true
});
```

Comment: Can you add the link to the plugin that you used? And also the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) to the experiment that you are working.

Comment: @KhoaPham: thanks. The plugin: https://github.com/vast-engineering/jquery-popup-overlay JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3t74x6v0/3/ (you'll need to add the plugin)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your jsfiddle example, I think there's nothing actually wrong with your code. It is just the issue with the link of your plugin source code is not working.

```
<script src="http://vast-engineering.github.io/jquery-popup-overlay/jquery.popupoverlay.js"></script>
```

If you visit that source link, you will see the 404 page instead of the source code. To resolve this, you can either download the source code from [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/vast-engineering/jquery-popup-overlay/gh-pages/jquery.popupoverlay.js), then host it on your own server. Or you can change your script to link to:

```
<script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/vast-engineering/jquery-popup-overlay/gh-pages/jquery.popupoverlay.js"></script>
```

I updated the working jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/3t74x6v0/9/).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yes. Nothing happens when I click on the buttons.

Comment: Very interesting. This is what I see when I visit that page: https://www.dropbox.com/s/4d7n8zaqirycol5/stackoverflow-screenshot.mov?dl=0
I think you might have some browser add-ons installed that prevent popup or something.